# How do you insert separators in something like an NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to learn how to use some kind of collection separator, such as in this example from Interface Builder:

[image: Interface Builder Example]

I haven't seen anything about these online, but I don't think I'm searching with the right keywords. Can someone point me in a direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example from Interface Builder is actually no real separator, it's just a custom NSCell.

Real separators, like available on the iPhone, always stay on top until the whole subgroup has been scrolled through. I hope you understand what i mean :)

To accomplish this, just create a custom cell. Make the cell look like this 'separator' and insert it at the appropriate index.

This might help understanding custom cells:

http://www.martinkahr.com/2007/05/04/nscell-image-and-text-sample/

Comment: "insert it at the appropriate index" - sounds easy enough... If I'm populating the table via an array controller, when should I insert?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still stuck on this. Instead of inserting the separators into my array of custom objects, I decided to try and intercept the calls to objectValueForTableColumn:row and instead return the separator text at the rows where I want them. I then tried to style the cells with -willDisplayCell, but I couldn't get very far (couldn't style the existing cell how I want). Could you elaborate on how you're inserting your custom nscells?

Answer (score 0):

A great example is Paul Kim's [`NoodleStickyRowTableView`](http://www.noodlesoft.com/blog/2009/09/25/sticky-section-headers-in-nstableview/), now part of [NoodleKit](https://github.com/MrNoodle/NoodleKit).  This in addition gives you the iPhone-like behavior of the separator "sticking" at the top of the table.